# connecting wakanda IDE to javascript

Tags: java, javascript, extjs, wakanda

> Wakanda IDE

is amazing, easy in implementing the interface, developing and everything.
 one problem i was still facing, i dont know how to connect my own java libraries into the wakanda server?
any information about this point?
[thats the link of the wakanda website](http://www.wakanda.org) i couldnt find any helpful information here.
 im going to officially work with this IDE once i can connect my libraries to it

Comment: can i also connect it with php?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, connecting Java libraries is not possible (you're talking about Java, not JavaScript, isn't it?). About JavaScript they implemented already a bunch of the most common ones, but it's at their discretion.

You better see Wakanda as a standalone for the moment. Wakanda is meant to be only JavaScript "from end to end". [see this article](http://opensource.sys-con.com/node/2305051)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is using the [SystemWorker API](http://doc.wakanda.org/System-Workers/System-Workers.100-775297.en.html) to interact Java (or PHP).

It use the same API provided by W3C/WATHWG Web Workers on command line executed processes.

I personally have been using it with PHP to use some PHP libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In Wakanda 11, the extension manager has many things you can add.

I am not sure what all is compatible, but I know that Wakanda 11 will let me know that node.js is missing or out-of-date. Ionic. Cordova. I am not sure if it is set up to work only with these (and a few others I did not list), or if this is evidence that other libraries can be used with Wakanda. Just a thought.